# Cant get my template to work. Illegal use of explicit template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

Im trying to use a template to pass through a class as a variable type to create my different units. It's saying this is an "illegal use of explicit template arguments".

```
template <class Type>
void Build<Type>()
{
    pUnit = new Type();
    unitArray.push_back(pUnit);
}
```

Do I have to somehow specify that the class Type is a Unit? When I change "template < class Type>" to "template < Unit Type>" it tells me that it is an "illegal type for non-type template parameter". I don't know what I need to do to make it legal.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of unitArray?

Comment: What's `pUnit`? What's `unitArray`? What line of code does the error point to?

Comment: I think you want `template <class Type> void MyClass<Type>::Build()`.

Answer (score 3):

"Illegal use of explicit template arguments" is simply your invalid function template declaration syntax. What is `<Type>` doing there after function template name? It is supposed to be just

```
template <class Type>
void Build()
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what unitArray is, so I'm assuming it is a vector of Types.
I can't tell what pUnit is either, and I'm assuming it is of type Type.

You have the function named Build, replace that with void Build(){}.

Unless this function is in a class implementation, you need to declare pUnit and unitArray as arguments of the types I mentioned above.

```
template <class Type>
void Build()
{
  pUnit = new Type;
  unitArray.push_back(pUnit);
}
```

## or

```
template <class Type>
void Build(vector<Type> unitArray, Type * pUnit)
{
  pUnit = new Type;
  unitArray.push_back(pUnit);
}
```